# windows phone 7 Recording Issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, microphone, video-recording

I will working on the Recording functionality in my windows phone 7 app.
I implemented the Recording functionality through this reference [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598930.aspx).

It completely works fine at there and in my case also.

Actually the scenario is, In my application i created first page that will works as the recording screen as same as above referred link.
and when we stop the recording i redirected to the second page and saved that recording in Isolated storage and at the second page i bound the recorded sounds. At here i played the recorded sounds at it works fine.

Now, when i m again go to the recording screen(first page) and starts another recording. it will some times records fine and some times it will skip the some sounds during recording as like beep sounds and it will looks like a extra noise in recording and not getting properly recording sounds.

My Code is like,

```
public partial class NikhilRecord : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //XNA Objects for Record And Playback
    Microphone mphone;

    //Used for Storing captured buffers
    List<byte[]> memobuffercollection = new List<byte[]>();

    //Used for displaying stored memos
    ObservableCollection<MemoInfo> memofiles = new ObservableCollection<MemoInfo>();

    SpaceTime spaceTime = new SpaceTime();

    public NikhilRecord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create new Microphone and set event handler.
        mphone = Microphone.Default;
        mphone.BufferReady += OnMicrophoneBufferReady;
        String FileName = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MySelectedSong"].ToString();

        using (IsolatedStorageFile IsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorage.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    MyMedia.SetSource(fileStream);                       
                    MyMedia.CurrentStateChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaPlayer_CurrentStateChanged);

                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();

                    //Start Recording
                    OnRecordButtonClick();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }

        void UpdateRecording(bool isRecording)
        {
           if (!isRecording)
           {
               using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
               {
                  spaceTime.Space = storage.AvailableFreeSpace;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               spaceTime.Space = memobuffercollection.Count * mphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(mphone.BufferDuration);
           }
           spaceTime.Time = mphone.GetSampleDuration((int)Math.Min(spaceTime.Space, Int32.MaxValue));            
        }
        void OnMicrophoneBufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get buffer from microphone and add to collection
            byte[] buffer = new byte[mphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(mphone.BufferDuration)];
            int bytesreturned = mphone.GetData(buffer);
            memobuffercollection.Add(buffer);

            UpdateRecording(true);
            // To be Continue...
            if (spaceTime.Time > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
            {
              StopRecording();
              UpdateRecording(false);
            }
        }
        void OnRecordButtonClick()
        {
           if (mphone.State == MicrophoneState.Stopped)
           {
               // Clear the collection for storing the buffers
               memobuffercollection.Clear();

               // Start Recording
               mphone.Start();
               MyMedia.Play();
           }
           else
           {
               MyMedia.Stop();
               //mphone.Stop();
               PopUpGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               RecordGrid.Opacity = 0.5;
               RecordGrid.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            }
            bool isRecording = mphone.State == MicrophoneState.Started;
            UpdateRecording(isRecording);
        }
        void StopRecording()
        {
           // Get the last partial buffer
           int sampleSize = mphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(mphone.BufferDuration);
           byte[] extraBuffer = new byte[sampleSize];
           int extraBytes = mphone.GetData(extraBuffer);

           // Stop Recording
           mphone.Stop();
           //Stop the Song
           MyMedia.Stop();

           // Create MemoInfo object and add at top of collection
           int totalSize = memobuffercollection.Count * sampleSize + extraBytes;
           TimeSpan duration = mphone.GetSampleDuration(totalSize);
           MemoInfo memoInfo = new MemoInfo(DateTime.UtcNow, totalSize, duration);
           memofiles.Insert(0, memoInfo);

           // Save Data in IsolatedStorage 
           using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
           {
              string[] alldirectories = storage.GetDirectoryNames("NikDirectory");
              if (alldirectories.Count() == 0)
                 storage.CreateDirectory("NikDirectory");
              try
              {
                 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile("NikDirectory\\" + memoInfo.FileName))
                 {
                    // Write buffers from collection
                    foreach (byte[] buffer in memobuffercollection)
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Write partial buffer
                    stream.Write(extraBuffer, 0, extraBytes);

                    stream.Close();
                    stream.Dispose();
                 }

                 Uri url = new Uri("/Gallery.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                 NavigationService.Navigate(url);
                 memobuffercollection.Clear();
              }
              catch (Exception ees)
              {
                 MessageBox.Show(ees.Message);
                 Uri url = new Uri("/Karaoke.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                 NavigationService.Navigate(url);
              }
           }
          bool isRecording = mphone.State == MicrophoneState.Started;
          UpdateRecording(isRecording);
       }
}
```

So, please help me out the problem. I heard at somewhere that you have to dispose all the objects of the microphone when you redirect to another screen. is it true ? or anything else.

Please help me. 
Looking Forward.

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried.

Comment: sure. i will edit my post with code. but actually there is nothing more change in that referred link

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a collection, you should use following way to read your recorded bytes.
This should be done into the BufferReady event of your microphone object.

```
 byte[] audioBuffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
                microphone.GetData(audioBuffer);                  
               RecordingStream.Write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);
```

RecordingStream is a `MemoryStream` , should be declared globally.

I am not sure about this but as I have used it and it works completely fine in each case.
Try this.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. But it will not solve my issue. Nothing improvements. getting same recording issue.

Comment: In my application when i am navigating on the another page. I clear all the object associated with the recording feature. I also set the Recording stream to null and clear microphone object. and when i come back to the same page again it starts recording with a new object of microphone and stream as well.

Comment: can you please show me or send me the whole code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please help me.
yet now, I stucked here. Looking forward.